# async req to load/render new page

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, request, rendering

Im working on a project, using firebase auth for login i.e. `login with google`; if logged in then redirect to `/app` where real functionalities of webapp exists.

login page js:

```js
document.getElementById('login').addEventListener('click', e => {
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

    firebase.auth()
        .signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then((result) => {
            firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(function(token) {
                //  make request to backend to get /app page where main app exists
                axios.get('/app', {
                    headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` } 
                })
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res.data);
                });
            });
        });

});
```

now my main motive is, user can't access pages other than `/` (landing page) without JWT token in header.

so here when user log in using `login With google` it will give token when logged in and then it will make req to backend with token and backend will return `/app` page pre-rendered!

### PROBLEM:   using this is code, when i make req to  backend it just return HTML code in `res.data` BUT i want actual page!!

Axios is well and good to fetch data from my backend api but i cant figure out how to attach header and make req, And get page instead of source code in response;

Same problem is occurring everywhere in application. I just don't want users to access pages other than landing page without JWT in header!

- backend: nodeJs
- firebase auth
- ejs template engine for view

---

**EDIT:**

meaning of returning source code is:
[img of console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzoAp.jpg)

---

any help, ideas or approach are welcome

Comment: What's the difference between a full code and the actual page?

Comment: Why not go for the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) api instead? no dependencies, faster load time, promise based, supports streams, and works in node (with node-fetch), Deno & web worker too

Comment: @Endless How does fetch API help here?

Comment: @rigojr where do you see React in the question?

Comment: Thankyou for response you'll.

first, I'm working on client side only with vanilla JS. (not using any frontend frameworks)

second, @ThomasSablik difference is, i want new page to load on frontend instead of getting it's source code in current page's javascript. get it?

Comment: You could write the JWT into a cookie and redirect to `/app` instead of loading data with AJAX. But you have to change the backend to read the token from the cookie. This way you can't set an Authorization header

Comment: Http requests made from your Javascript in the browser do NOT change the HTML displayed in the browser at all.  If you want that HTML to change, you have to write Javascript to get the response from the http request and actually change the currently displayed page.  You can do that either by setting `window.location` to a new URL and thus telling the browser to go to a new page or you can dynamically insert content into the currently viewed web page.

Comment: @ThomasSablik yes good idea, but then again, i'm not really sure about this.
as firebase user session already lives in client side i.e. cookies namely.
so IDK if it's really the best option for now. It would be really great just if i could attach header to each req that leaves my browser so server can check it and respond acc. to it!

Comment: Actually it's the only option if you don't want to use a framework like Angular or React or build your own AJAX based DOM manipulation framework. Therefore it's the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Login as before
2. Write the token into a cookie instead of the Authorization header
3. Redirect the browser to `/app`
4. In the backend read the cookie instead of the Authorization header

This way the browser will solve the problem for you by rendering the response. Using cookies is the usual way to implement a login without AJAX.

It's not possible to make a redirect and set the Authorization header.

Comment: ok, lemme implement it first.
if it works as smoothly as it sounds then i will mark your comment as answer.

Thankyou for response, really appreciate it man!

Comment: Thanks for guiding,
i've implemented it. So far, it's very satisfying